# How to treat NAs like values when comparing elementwise in R

Tags: arrays, r, na

I want to compare two vectors elementwise to check whether an element in a certain position in the first vector is different from the element in the same position in the second vector.
The point is that I have `NA` values inside the vectors, and when doing the comparison for these values I get `NA` instead of `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

**Reproducible example:**

Here is what I get:

```r
a<-c(1, NA, 2, 2, NA)
b<-c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA)
a!=b
[1] FALSE   TRUE   NA   NA   NA
```

Here is how I would like the `!=` operator to work (treat `NA` values as if they were just another "level" of the variable):

```
a!=b
[1] FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
```

There's a possible solution at [this link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Comparing_vectors_or_factors_with_NA/), but the guy is creating a function to perform the task. I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do that.

Comment: How do you get TRUE values for the second case.  It should be FALSE as we are comparing NA with 1

Comment: Could you use a dummy value instead of NA?  e.g. `a[is.na(a)] <- 999`.

Comment: @akrun I get `TRUE` because `NA` is different (not equal) from 1.  

@Bazz yes, I thought of that solution and it works too, but I would like to have a more elegant solution without having to make the imputation as I should have to reconvert the values fo NA after the comparison (I have a very large dataset so it's not very practical)

Comment: Are you looking for new examples to update the post?

Comment: can you update your output/explain more clearly what you try to achieve?

Comment: Which solution did you use in the end?

Comment: @akrun is right that the indicated results are not reproducible. 
```a<-c(1, NA, 2, 2, NA);
b<-c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA);
a!=b;
[1] FALSE    NA  TRUE    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taking advantage of the fact that:

`T & NA = NA`
but
`F & NA = F`

and

`F | NA = NA`
but
`T | NA = T`

The following solution works, with carefully placed brackets:

```
(a != b | (is.na(a) & !is.na(b)) | (is.na(b) & !is.na(a))) & !(is.na(a) & is.na(b))
```

You could define:

```
`%!=na%` <- function(e1, e2) (e1 != e2 | (is.na(e1) & !is.na(e2)) | (is.na(e2) & !is.na(e1))) & !(is.na(e1) & is.na(e2))
```

and then use:

```
a %!=na% b
```

Comment: This works, but I'll leave the question open as you're performing a variation of the function in the link I put in the description. I posted the question to find a simpler solution (if it exists).

Comment: @hellter That's fine.  You're right it does seem like an inelegant solution to something quite simple.

Answer (score 7):

I like this one, since it is pretty simple and it's easy to see that it works ([source](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Comparing_vectors_or_factors_with_NA/)):

```R
# This function returns TRUE wherever elements are the same, including NA's,
# and FALSE everywhere else.
compareNA <- function(v1, v2) 
{
    same <- (v1 == v2) | (is.na(v1) & is.na(v2))
    same[is.na(same)] <- FALSE
    return(same)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution.  It's probably slower than my other answer because it's not vectorised, but it's certainly more elegant.  I noticed the other day that `%in%` compares `NA` like other values.  Thus `c(1L, NA) %in% 1:4` gives `TRUE  FALSE` rather than `TRUE  NA`, for example.

So you can have:

```
!mapply(`%in%`, a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could perform an on-the-fly replacement of the NA values with a value `v1` which is not present in both the vectors and do the `!=`

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {
  v1 <- setdiff(1:1000, na.omit(unique(c(x,y))))[1]
  replace(x, is.na(x), v1) != replace(y, is.na(y), v1)
}

f1(a,b)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
f1(a1,b1)
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
f1(a2,b2)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

#### data

```
a <- c(1, NA, 2, 2, NA)
b<-c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA)
a1 <- c(NA, 1, NA)
b1 <- c(2, NA, 3) 
a2<-c(1,NA,2,NA)
b2<-c(1,1,3,NA)
```

Comment: I forgot to add the case in which I compare two `NA` values: in that case, I want the comparison to return `FALSE`. Moreover, I would like to have a solution which works both if I have the NAs in the first vector that in the second. I edited the question.

Comment: This returns `FALSE` in the second position when it should be `TRUE`.

Comment: @Bazz Why should it be TRUE??

Comment: Because `a[2]` is `NA` and `b[2]` is `1`, so they're different.

Comment: @Bazz That is my point.  They are different, so it should return FALSE

Comment: As @Bazz pointed out, the updated solution  `a!= b & !is.na(a) & !is.na(b)` doesn't work as it returns `FALSE` for the second element: in fact, I'd like to treat NAs like if they were integers, returning `TRUE` for the comparison of the second element.

Comment: @hellter So, if the value in `a <- c(NA, 1, NA); b <- c(2, NA, 3)` what would be the result?

Comment: @akrun it should be `TRUE` `TRUE` `TRUE`

Comment: @helter Can you check now.

Comment: @Bazz Please remove your comments from my post as it is not relevant now

Comment: This would not work, as `replace(a, is.na(a), FALSE)` substitutes `NA` values with 0. This could be a problem in the case where `a<-0; b<-NA`, which would return `FALSE` instead of `TRUE` (0 **is** different from `NA`).

Comment: @hellter In that case you can replace it with some other value.  I have showed 3 cases where it works

Comment: @akrun yes you're right, but first I should look for a value which is **NOT** included in both vectors to avoid mistakes (running`unique()` on both vectors or something like that)

Comment: @hellter  something like `setdiff(1:1000, na.omit(unique(c(a, b))))[1]`

Comment: Exactly. So the solution would still be to do a simple pairwise comparison but making an on-the-fly imputation of `NA` values, which only exists for the comparison. Could you implement the `setdiff()` part inside the function? This seems to me like quite a good way to solve the problem

Comment: @helter added that par

Comment: `1:1000`?? What kind of dirty hack is that? This will not work.

Comment: @akrun so how will that work for vectors longer than 1000?

Comment: I don't remember the context on which this was answered.  It is close to ~ 4 years back.