# R convert NA value to character for string comparison

Tags: r, string, na

I have a dataframe that contains 2 columns with character strings. The goal is to see how many of them are identical including `NA` values. If both columns give `NA`, it should be treated as identical.

```
class(df$column_1) # it shows characters
length(which(df$column_1 == df$column_2)) # the result exclude the NA rows
```

Comment: `length(which(df$column_1 == df$column_2, x = T))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to ask in addition to `is.na`:

```
length(which(x$a == x$b | (is.na(x$a) & is.na(x$b))))
#[1] 2
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(a=c("a", NA, "b"), b=c("c", NA, "b"))
```

Comment: great! thanks! it works. what does this "which(is.na(i) | i)" exactly mean?

Comment: The part `s.na(x$a) & is.na(x$b)` tests if both are at the same time `NA`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be using `identical()` (which has a nice property that `identical(NA, NA) = TRUE`) term by term with a loop:

Dummy data:

```
a=c("a",NA,"b")
b=c(NA,NA,"d")
df = data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Code:

```
count = 0
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  count = count + identical(df[i,1],df[i,2])}
```

Output:

```
>count
>1
```

Comment: or perhaps: `with(df, sum(mapply(identical, a, b)))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, why not put that as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37610056/1217536), where it will be better able to be found?